# How to implement a cancel of a method execution (e.g. cancel of foreign API call, that takes too long time) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, webserver, connection-pooling

Is it possible (I think it is a usual thing) to cancel a request (also a method which already started on the server after this request)?

Say, I request from a rails app a video search on youtube or vimeo (which is implemented on the server and makes further requests directly to vimeo or youtube), but then I decide to cancel this search, so I can start a new one, without waisting the resources for already useless search results. So all requests are done via AJAX.

I think I should:

- either define a global variable (e.g. `cancel_req = 4939498348953` and each time when cancell set it to some specific ID known to the method I desire to cancel, and in the mean time just set to `cancel = nil`. So at some points in the code just check this variable (but what if the 3rd party API call is blocking with very long duration time, because it returns very much data?)
- or introduce redis subscribing (I think its a bit over-engineered for this task)

But both methods sounds to me like just a workarounds. Are there any better ways to reach the `cancel` of those long-running methods like requesting 3rd parties APIs in own solution?

## Update:

is it somehow possible in rails with `callbacks`? maybe with `yield`s?

## Update2:

The workflow is following:

```
client -> webserver -> rails-app-server (controller/helper) --->
                                                                |
                                                           foreignAPI  // <-- break execution somewhere here (but of course still handle all other client requests, so - not exiting the application) 
                                                                |  
 client <- webserver <- rails-app-server (controller/helper) <--
```

Comment: So you're making the request from your controller?

Comment: just updated the scheme. yes, in the controller there is a call for a foreign API, which can take a long time, so it is blocking the client to make another search

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is simply blocking calls. Consider [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to run asynchronous tasks--in your case, these long API calls. You can set the configuration `Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 10.seconds` (or whatever time) as the limit you're willing to wait, and there are callbacks for pretty much every event you can think of.

Comment: Thank you for the links! Hm, I think it is not only about callbacks, but about how to make this call responsive (so when the client doesn't want to wait anymore - the task could be killed interactively (semi-interactively) just by making another ajax request, without getting the response from the first one anymore)

Comment: I don't know. I pretty much design everything to be asynchronous where the client isn't waiting for anything and the result arrives when it arrives. Haven't handled this use case before.